# get 10-bit RGB value from 10 bit video

Tags: ffmpeg, png, hdr

I tried to extract frames from 10 bit video using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i 10-bit-video.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb16be test_%03d.png
```

and that's 16-bit png with max value of 65535

how to get corresponding 10-bit RGB value (0-1023) from extracted 16-bit PNG?

Comment: Divide by 1024.

Comment: why divide by 1024? 0~65536 / 1024 is in 0~64

Comment: Sorry, I meant 64.

Comment: thank you, I'll have a try !

Comment: That should be the case, Gyan, but it is not. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7978#comment:6 in ffmpeg just converting 10 bit 940 value to png does not get you to 60160.